# Rails + How do I assign dedicated workers to Resque queues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-scheduler

Here, trying to assign dedicated workers to specific queues in Resque.

For example - 2 Workers are dedicated to **default** Queue, and 4 dedicated workers to the **high** queue.

[image: resque-queues]

Here, 16 workers to dedicated queues and the remaining 4 workers to any of the queues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using resque as background job for my rails app

here my answer probably can help you

```bash
cd /rails_app/

RAILS_ENV=production rake resque:work QUEUE='default' BACKGROUND=yes 
RAILS_ENV=production rake resque:work QUEUE='default' BACKGROUND=yes 
typing 2 times command above will run 2 worker for specific queue

RAILS_ENV=production rake resque:work QUEUE='high' BACKGROUND=yes 
type 4 times if you want to run this queue with 4 workers
```

**additional notes**

**queue name also can be use for order job as priority**
for example I have 01_high, 02_default, 03_low
and I run the worker as command below

RAILS_ENV=production rake resque:work QUEUE='*' BACKGROUND=yes

number 01_high has higher priority, it will process 02_default until 01_high finished